# How to post the date in DB?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mongoose

I would like to `POST` in my DB `Date.now` but nothing shows up. Do I have to declare in app ass well or it suppose to work from backend?

This is from my mongoose Schema

```
postDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

and here is from my controller

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
   var user = req.user;
   var postDate = req.body.postDate;
   var count = user.jobs.push({
      postDate: postDate
   });
   user.save(function(err) {
   if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json({job: {
         postDate: postDate,
      }});
   })
}
```

Comment: Have you verified `var postDate` is defined?

Comment: What do you mean? is right after `var user`

Comment: I meant the value of the variable `postDate`.  If you did `typeof postDate`, what would the result be?

Comment: My error. In my javascript the state of `postDate` was undefined now I've changed with `postDate: (new Date()).toLocaleString(),`

Comment: Now the problem is that it store in DB like YYYY-DD-MM and moment js read it like YYYY-MM-DD so instead having the post old by couple of seconds or minutes it shows like 4 months old

Comment: Date.now() returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01. You must change your schema to contain a Number instead of a Date.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp

Comment: does postDate is a Date Object? When you don't provide any postdate (so if you remove var postDate = req.body.postDate;) you will have the date when you save the document.